# "BadValueError: Filtering on Text properties is not supported" on a StringProperty using AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am running AppEngine locally. I use some filters on the following attribute of my object:

```
class Blah(db.Model):
    access_code = db.StringProperty()
```

Then I run my filter in the view:

```
cac = Blah.all().filter(
    'access_code =', 'value_to_find').fetch(1)
```

When doing so, I get the following error: `BadValueError: Filtering on Text properties is not supported.`

Even though it's a `StringProperty`. This never happened before and a few searches on Google didn't help at all. 
Is anyone having the same issue?

Comment: Is 'value_to_find' a hard-coded string or a variable?

Comment: it's a variable actually

Comment: Is the variable in quotes, like in your example?

Comment: It seems likely that the variable you're passing in is of type `db.Text`, instead of `unicode`.

Answer (score 1):

Was the access_code field ever a TextProperty at some point in your application's life? Even if you changed you model definition, any entities that were added to the datastore while it was a Text will remain a Text. You can use the Admin console's data store viewer to look up the specific entity that is causing this problem to make sure that it's access_code field is definitely a StringProperty and not a TextProperty.

Comment: No all of them are StringProperty. I've just deleted all of them and rebatched the whole import .. still have the same error.

Comment: That was what occurred to me first, too, but that won't cause this error - it'd just lead to missing entries in the result set.